# QProgressDialog doesn't paint during initializeGL

Tags: c++, qt, progressdialog

I'm using a `QProgressDialog` to display the progress of my `initializeGL()` function but the little window show up unpainted... Here's the simplified code :

```
QProgressDialog barTest("Wait","Ok", 0, 100, this);

barTest.move(400,400);

barTest.show();

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    barTest.setValue(i);
    qDebug() << i;
}
```

I'm running `Mac OS 10.8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the paint event for the window is stuck in Qt's Event Loop as long as you are executing code (e.g. the `for` loop).

If you want the paint events to be processed, you can use [QApplication::processEvents](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    barTest.setValue(i);
    qDebug() << i;

    // handle repaints (but also any other event in the queue)
    QApplication::processEvents();
}
```

Dependent on the quickness of the loop you might find it sufficient to update only each 10% for instance:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    barTest.setValue(i);
    qDebug() << i;

    // handle repaints (but also any other event in the queue)
    if(i % 10 == 0) QApplication::processEvents();
}
```